# VBA Loop to fill a table

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I wanted to write a macro to fill a table on Sheet2 using data in Sheet1.
I will first count the number of period in Sheet1, and then in Sheet2, there are 3 rows that need to be filled using data in Sheet1 for each period. The rule can be seen from the labeled color.

The code that I wrote is not working correctly to fill the table. I wasn't able to figure out the right way to solve this. Can anyone please help？ Thank you in advance!

```
Sub fillDate()

Dim periods As Long, i As Integer, j As Integer
    periods = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row - 7

For i = 2 To 2 + (periods - 1) * 3 Step 3
    For j = 1 To periods
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 3).Value
           
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 0).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 3).Value
           
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(2, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(2, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(2, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(2, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Offset(j, 3).Value
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rearrange Data

[image]

```vb
Sub ReArrangeData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "E7"
    Dim sArr(): sArr = VBA.Array( _
        VBA.Array(2, 2, 2, 5, 1), _
        VBA.Array(2, 2, 4, 5, 1), _
        VBA.Array(4, 4, 4, 5, 1))
    
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write the source data to an array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim sData(), srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).CurrentRegion
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        sData = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1).Value
    End With
    
    ' Return the rearranged data in another array.
    
    Dim rUpper As Long: rUpper = UBound(sArr)
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(sArr(0))
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = cUpper + 1
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To srCount * (rUpper + 1), 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For r = 0 To rUpper
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 0 To cUpper
                dData(dr, c + 1) = sData(sr, sArr(r)(c))
            Next c
        Next r
    Next sr
 
    ' Write the rearranged data to the destination range.
 
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    
    Dim drg As Range:
    Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(dr, dcCount)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data rearranged.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008, I'm trying to understand how it works. Kind of difficult for me.  The Period number column is not in Sheet1 actually (So Sheet2 should not have Period number column neither), I wrote it to indicate the logic. So how should I modify the code if there is no Period number column?

Comment: The key to figuring out how this works lies in understanding what `sArr` represents. It is a 1D zero-based array with 3 elements each of them representing a row. Each of these 3 elements is another 1D zero-based array with 5 elements each of them representing a column. So if the number 2 is used to return `12/2/2021` it's not that hard to figure out that if you don't have the `Period` column to use `1` instead and if there are only 4 columns, to get rid of each 5th element representing the `Period` column with e.g. `... VBA.Array(1, 1, 1, 4)...`.

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 , I figured that out! Another question is that what is the purpose of the following line: drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear, thank you

Comment: It clears any data below the result. If e.g. previously you had 5 rows in the source and now you have 3, it clears the 6 (2*3) rows remaining from the previous result.